# How to pass a shell variable into xsl with xsltproc?

Tags: shell, xslt

I want to pass a variable `name=$(echo "$t" | cut -f 1 -d '.')`
 from shell script to the following xsl as $name variable:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dc:record">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *" />
        <xsl:param name="name"/>
         <dc:relation><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></dc:relation>    
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is it possible to send the variable via `xsltproc -o ie1.xml ../../transform.xsl ie1.xml` and how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Define the `xsl:param` at the top-level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:param name="name" />
...
```

Then call `xsltproc` with the `--stringparam` parameter

```
xsltproc --stringparam name "$name" -o ie1.xml ../../transform.xsl ie1.xml
```

That's all.

Comment: Interestingly, it works with the `--stringparam` even **without** declaring the `xsl:param`.